# How to recover deleted file in Linux

Tags: linux, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover a removed file under linux](https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux)

I have run the rm -rf * command mistakenly at the [user]@localhost location. Because of that I lost all the files in my user account. Please tell me if there a way to recover those deleted files.

Comment: In order for any tool to have success you need to boot to another hdd and from this point on only have read access to the hdd with the data you want to recover.  If you don't have access to this capability then you are pretty much out of luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover a removed file under linux](http://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux), http://superuser.com/questions/105120/linux-file-recovery, http://superuser.com/questions/100298/free-data-recovery-tool-for-linux

Answer (score 1):

Just copy everything from the last backup. Do you make backups, right?

Comment: Any data not worth backing up is not worth recovering.